# Is it possible to run a bash script that restarts a discord bot?

Tags: node.js, bash, discord.js, child-process

I've been working on a discord bot in which there's a command that pulls code from discord, and then it should restart the bot in order for that code to take effect. Is there a shell script that can accomplish this?

I've tried out multiple types, like running `npx forever restart bot.js` and chaining multiple `exec()` files together, but nothing seems to work.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
let script = exec(
    path.join(__dirname, "test.bat"),
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`error: ${error}`);
        }
        console.log("finished");
    }
);
```

```sh
    git pull origin master
    npm run start
    echo "done"
    pause
```

Comment: Check out [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti worked perfectly, thank you